# Bulk Insert of Generic List C# into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, bulkinsert

How can I bulk insert a generic list in c# into SQL Server, rather than looping through the list and inserting individual items one at a time?

I currently have this;

```
private void AddSnapshotData()
{
  var password =       Cryptography.DecryptString("vhx7Hv7hYD2bF9N4XhN5pkQm8MRfxi+kogALYqwqSuo=");
  var figDb = "ZEUS";
  var connString =
    String.Format(
      "Data Source=1xx.x.xx.xxx;Initial Catalog={0};;User ID=appuser;Password={1};MultipleActiveResultSets=True",
      figDb, password);
  var myConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);
  myConnection.Open();

  foreach (var holding in _dHoldList)
  {
    lbStatus.Text = "Adding information to SQL for client: " + holding.ClientNo;
    _reports.AddZeusData("tblAllBrooksHoldingsSnapshot", "CliNo, SEDOL, ISIN, QtyHeld, DateOfSnapshot",
                         "'" + holding.ClientNo + "','" + holding.Sedol + "','" + holding.ISIN + "','" +
                         holding.QuantityHeld + "','" + DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "'", false, myConnection);
  }
  myConnection.Close();
  lbStatus.Visible = false;
}
```

Where `dHoldList` is a list of `DHOLDS`;

```
public class DHOLDS : ExcelReport
 {
public String ClientNo { get; set; }
public String Sedol { get; set; }
public Double QuantityHeld { get; set; }
public Double ValueOfStock { get; set; }
public String Depot { get; set; }
public String ValC4 { get; set; }
public String StockR1 { get; set; }
public String StockR2 { get; set; }
public Double BookCost { get; set; }
public String ISIN { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: More info on how you plan to store it would be helpful, can you use your own methods? or do you have to use some existing answers in "_reports"?

Comment: I can use my own methods, and the DB belongs to me so I can add or make any changes I wish.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may map your list to a datatable and then use [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) to insert all the rows at once.

Comment: This method would require that you convert your list to a DataTable before you can save it but it would be the fastest way from a SQL Server perspective...

Comment: Seconded. I have found this the fastest way to load data into SQL Server from outside the server.

Comment: Best of luck to you if you want to get the identity values back though.  Anyone know of anything that works better with relational data?

Comment: This is correct answer. Check this [article for example](http://blog.developers.ba/bulk-insert-generic-list-sql-server-minimum-lines-code/) how to use SqlBulkCopy with minimum lines of code.

Answer (score 9):

4 years later this is my contribution. I had the same problem, I wanted to to bulk insert but passing over some fields that weren't going to be in the database, specifically EF navigation properties, so I wrote this generic class:

```
/// <summary>
/// This class is intended to perform a bulk insert of a list of elements into a table in a Database. 
/// This class also allows you to use the same domain classes that you were already using because you
/// can include not mapped properties into the field excludedPropertyNames.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The class that is going to be mapped.</typeparam>
public class BulkInsert<T> where T : class
{
    #region Fields

    private readonly LoggingService _logger = new LoggingService(typeof(BulkInsert<T>));
    private string _connectionString;
    private string _tableName;
    private IEnumerable<string> _excludedPropertyNames;
    private int _batchSize;
    private IEnumerable<T> _data;
    private DataTable _dataTable;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BulkInsert{T}"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionString">The connection string.</param>
    /// <param name="tableName">Name of the table.</param>
    /// <param name="data">The data.</param>
    /// <param name="excludedPropertyNames">The excluded property names.</param>
    /// <param name="batchSize">Size of the batch.</param>
    public BulkInsert(
        string connectionString,
        string tableName,
        IEnumerable<T> data,
        IEnumerable<string> excludedPropertyNames,
        int batchSize = 1000)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionString));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableName)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tableName));
        if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));
        if (batchSize <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(batchSize));

        _connectionString = connectionString;
        _tableName = tableName;
        _batchSize = batchSize;
        _data = data;
        _excludedPropertyNames = excludedPropertyNames == null ? new List<string>() : excludedPropertyNames;
        _dataTable = CreateCustomDataTable();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Inserts the data with a bulk copy inside a transaction. 
    /// </summary>
    public void Insert()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

            using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, transaction))
            {
                bulkCopy.BatchSize = _batchSize;
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = _tableName;

                // Let's fix tons of mapping issues by
                // Setting the column mapping in SqlBulkCopy instance:
                foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in _dataTable.Columns)
                {
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(dataColumn.ColumnName, dataColumn.ColumnName);
                }

                try
                {
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(_dataTable);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }

            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Helper Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the custom data table.
    /// </summary>
    private DataTable CreateCustomDataTable()
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        var table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
        {
            // Just include the not excluded columns
            if (_excludedPropertyNames.All(epn => epn != prop.Name))
            {                  
                if (prop.PropertyType.Name == "DbGeography")
                {
                    var type = typeof(SqlGeography);
                    table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, type);
                }
                else
                {
                    table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (T item in _data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            {
                // Just include the values in not excluded properties 
                if (_excludedPropertyNames.All(epn => epn != prop.Name))
                {
                    if (prop.PropertyType.Name == "DbGeography")
                    {                           
                        row[prop.Name] = SqlGeography.Parse(((DbGeography)prop.GetValue(item)).AsText()).MakeValid();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
                    }
                }
            }
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }

    #endregion

}
```

It's usage would be like:

```
//1st.- You would have a colection of entities:
var myEntities = new List<MyEntity>();
// [...] With thousands or millions of items

// 2nd.- You would create the BulkInsert:
myEntityTypeBulk = new BulkInsert<MyEntity>(_connectionString, "MyEntitiesTableName", myEntities, new[] { "ObjectState", "SkippedEntityProperty1", "SkippedEntityProperty2" });

// 3rd.- You would execute it:
myEntityTypeBulk.Insert();
```

The performance gained and the reusability of this class were worth this message. I hope it helps:

Juan

Comment: What is SqlGeography?

Comment: I Should have commented that, well, that fix a common problem when you use geospatial data with Entity Framework, the types are not the same, your entities will use DbGeography, the type that EF knows and uses for this purpose, but to insert it into SQL it has to be SqlGeography.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could convert your list to XML as well, as described in this blogpost: http://charleskong.com/blog/2009/09/insert-aspnet-objects-to-sql-server/
But the SqlBulkCopy approach seems better.

Another remark: if you want to solve it through iterating over the elements in code, than it could possible improve performance if you do all the inserts in one single transaction.

Comment: I am doing all the inserts in one transaction? I disconnect after all the loop has compeleted?

Comment: I mean making use of an SQLTransaction. by opening a Transaction on the Connection like var t = connection.BeginTransaction(); adding it to the SQLMethod that executes the querry and calling t.Commit(); after the loop. See this stackoverflow-question for info, about why it can be faster: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091084/ado-net-sqltransaction-improves-performance

Answer (score 0):

Juan's solution worked perfect for me, so I've made a few more changes and now supports async and a few refactoring

```
public class BulkInsert<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    private readonly string _tableName;
    private readonly IEnumerable<string>? _excludedPropertyNames;
    private readonly int _batchSize;
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> _data;
    private readonly DataTable _dataTable;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BulkInsert{T}"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionString">The connection string.</param>
    /// <param name="tableName">Name of the table.</param>
    /// <param name="data">The data.</param>
    /// <param name="excludedPropertyNames">The excluded property names.</param>
    /// <param name="batchSize">Size of the batch.</param>
    public BulkInsert(
        string connectionString,
        string tableName,
        IEnumerable<T> data,
        IEnumerable<string>? excludedPropertyNames,
        int batchSize = 1000)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionString));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableName)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tableName));
        if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));
        if (batchSize <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(batchSize));

        _connectionString = connectionString;
        _tableName = tableName;
        _batchSize = batchSize;
        _data = data;
        _excludedPropertyNames = excludedPropertyNames ?? new List<string>();
        _dataTable = CreateCustomDataTable();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inserts the data with a bulk copy inside a transaction.
    /// </summary>
    public async Task InsertAsync()
    {
        await using var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

        using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, transaction))
        {
            bulkCopy.BatchSize = _batchSize;
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = _tableName;

            // Let's fix tons of mapping issues by
            // Setting the column mapping in SqlBulkCopy instance:
            foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in _dataTable.Columns)
            {
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(dataColumn.ColumnName, dataColumn.ColumnName);
            }

            try
            {
                await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(_dataTable);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                await transaction.RollbackAsync();
                await connection.CloseAsync();
            }
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the custom data table.
    /// </summary>
    private DataTable CreateCustomDataTable()
    {
        var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        var table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
        {
            // Just include the not excluded columns
            if (_excludedPropertyNames != null && _excludedPropertyNames.All(epn => epn != prop.Name))
            {
                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
            }
        }
        foreach (T item in _data)
        {
            var row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            {
                // Just include the values in not excluded properties
                if (_excludedPropertyNames != null && _excludedPropertyNames.All(epn => epn != prop.Name))
                {
                    row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
                }
            }
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
```