# SQL Server 2008 big INSERT still slow after wrapped in transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been looking at a big INSERT problem in my query:

```
INSERT table_name
SELECT .....;
```

The table has no indexes and needs about 20 million rows to insert into it. I run the query in SQL Server 2008 R2 on one of our servers. The original performance is about 40 minutes. I then read posts here telling me to wrap the `INSERT` in `BEGIN TRANSACTION` / `COMMIT`. I did that, and the time spent dropped to 6 minutes.

However, when I tried to run the transaction wrapped query for next few times, the time went back to 40 minutes, like the `TRANSACTION` effect is gone. I don't know what happened in the following runs. Any idea?

ADD:

One other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521887/how-much-does-wrapping-inserts-in-a-transaction-help-performance-on-sql-server) says TRANSACTION is intended to be used for data consistency not performance, suggesting batch insert every 5K rows. How can I break up above single INSERT SELECT statement to batches? I am confused.

UPDATE:

Indeed, I find the performance improvement is not from TRANSACTION, but possibly is from server side table caching, as I run next few times and performance are like 5 minutes.

Comment: How much time does the `select` alone take ?

Comment: @Lostdreamer the SELECT is only 5% of the total, according to execution plan estimate by SQL Server

Comment: are you using any front end coding to insert data or just running sql query in query editor?

Comment: You said that you have no indexe, but do you have a primary key ?

Comment: As stated in the other post, transactions have nothing to do with performance. The speed-increase you noticed had little to do with the transaction (if anything at all).

Comment: What recovery model is the database running in? Is it a production database that needs to be fed with 20m rows regularly, or are you performing a one-time only operation?

Comment: @Lostdreamer don't have primary key, does that matter in any way?

Comment: @SchmitzIT I really want to know what gave me that once-off huge boost. :-(

Comment: @Sheen - Hard to say without knowing more. If the server was rebooted right before you did it, that could be a reason. We have no information to go on really, so it's pretty difficult to say why something did or did not happen. In any case, wrapping your SQL code in a transaction should not be an explanation for the script running faster. In fact, I would expect the reverse to happen.

Answer (score 1):

When you wrap many `INSERT ... VALUES` statements in a transaction, a massive speed-up is likely because you don't have to write dirty data pages to disk after every insert.  However, when you wrap a single `INSERT ... SELECT` in an explicit transaction, there is no speed-up, because there was an implicit transaction even before and the mechanics haven't really changed.  Most likely something else changed in your environment at the same time.

The gradual performance drop is presumably due to either the target table growing, or the database growing as a result of that.  The former will never stop growing, the latter might get a little more variable/unpredictable as your database keeps growing, so it is probably not a drop, it is a trend.

If you can always ensure inserting data to an empty table, consider being more radical and drop it every time.  Use `SELECT INTO` instead of `INSERT ... SELECT`.  This may or may not work with your referential integrity needs.  The advantage of the different syntax is a different logging strategy.

If the table cannot be dropped before the next insert, but you can ensure that it is never accessed by other connections during the `INSERT` operation, you can use isolation levels or table hints to take locking out of your way; however, a much safer method to a similar goal is the `TABLOCK` hint.  This hint sort of goes to the extreme opposite by locking the whole table at the beginning; everyone else is excluded and no time is spent on row level locking.

Insert the data sorted by the (clustered) primary key of the target table.  You may consider temporarily disabling the *other* indexes during your `INSERT`, but do not go this way lightly as it is just another way of severely hurting any concurrent traffic if any exists.

Watch your mdf file size.  Avoid situations where you see it growing automatically by small increments.

Last resort: do some HW utilization planning and partition the target table.  For this, you need to switch from the "faster, please" mindset to "I need to achieve exactly this speed" mindset.  This is significantly more complicated to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a lot of things that can affect this. Type of logging being used, what else is going on the server, is operation able to get exclusive lock on table, hardware (mainly disk IO), what indexes already exisit on the table, etc.

Inserting 20 million records will generate a lot of logging. You want to ensure you are performing minimally logged operation. For this, consider SELECT INTO (if possible). But if you are stuck with INSERT SELECT, consider the facotrs that enable SELECT INTO to be a minimally logged operation. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your MSDN link. WITH (TABLOCK) is useful in my case.

Answer (score 0):

To insert bulk data quickly, use Bulk Copy.

You can use the BCP utility:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

Or, from .Net or you can use the Sql Native Client:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130809(v=SQL.100).aspx

Alternatively to do a batch-type copy within a database:

```
declare @todo table( primaryKeyFieldName primary key)
insert @todo select primaryKeyFieldName from SourceTable

declare @batch table(primaryKeyFieldName primary key)
delete @batch
while exists (select 1 from @todo)
begin 
    insert @batch select top 500 primaryKeyFieldName from @todo
    delete todo from @todo todo inner join @batch b on b.primaryKeyFieldName = todo.primaryKeyFieldName 
    insert DestinationTable(fields....)
    select s.fields, ....
    from SourceTable s inner join @batch b on s.primaryKeyFieldName = b.primaryKeyFieldName
end
```

Comment: I am not copying or backing up data out to file or other source, I have to run SELECT SQL query to get selected data from some tables, project them into a big table. These suggestions sound irrelevant to my problem but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a regular task you need to carry why cant you create a SSIS package and run it whenever you have to perform this.

Comment: This is a daily task to simply join 2 big tables and put results in target table, all in same database. How would SSIS package help improve performance?

Comment: SSIS will allow you to break it up into batches.

Comment: also SSIS is mucu faster than regular query for insertion

Answer (score 0):

I just tested with "WITH (TABLOCK)" hint and finally got satisfactory performance. The whole query runs for 3 minutes comparing to original 40 minutes. This is huge improvement and because the query is doing initial table population work, no worry about access conflict.

Thank you all for your helpfull comment.