# UPDATE statement performance for 100+ concurrent users

Tags: database-design, sql-server-2012

I'm developing a small application in C#. Backend SQL Server 2012. It is a ticket generation module. The Ticket table consists of 61 columns. For Every ticket keyed in an entry is inserted in this table. As and when some changes are done to the ticket, such updates are also done in this table.

We will be having about 100 or more users simultaneously doing the ticketing.(The necessary Transaction looping etc., are in place).

My doubt is - is it correct to have many users update the same table. Will it not slow down the application?

I could not test it since, I do not have this kind of a setup. If Anyone here has an experience please suggest the right way.

Thank you.

Googled, but could not get the right track.

Comment: You have one table with 61 columns? That sounds like super bad table design.

Comment: Yes, probably.  The entire ticket details with the discount, paymodes etc are all stored in that table itself.  Even if I'd remove the payment, discount and taxes options..yet would be left with 30 columns.  I have to do it anyways... But before that I want a clarification on the question.

Comment: You could have a couple of tables where one is for master and another one is for transaction. Using Separate tables would make the design easy and more efficient while querying data.

Comment: Thank you for all your time and guidance @juergend d

Comment: Thank you for all your time and guidance @SrinivasanRajasekaran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100 is actually a pretty small number provided that they are not connecting to the DB with different accounts (so you have a business layer which is handling all of these connections, with a specific DB account)

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-user-connections-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017.

This information is for SQL Server 2017, but I'd imagine 2012 would be fairly similar.

Some more good reads here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/transaction-fundamentals
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43254/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-always-create-a-transaction
- [How much does wrapping inserts in a transaction help performance on Sql Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521887/how-much-does-wrapping-inserts-in-a-transaction-help-performance-on-sql-server)

**If your transaction logic (correctly implemented) is in place, 100+ users should be ok.**

This is not to say that it would be fast though. Depending on your **SQL Server machine configuration**, it might be terribly slow. It depends on the machine that SQL server is running as well as your network connections.

*Also - 61 columns per table doesn't sound good.*

Comment: Thank you for your time and guidance. Thank you for the links.