# Why SQLite queries run slower in Windows [server] machine compared to Ubuntu & MacOS?

Tags: c++, sqlite, select, database-performance, windows-server-2012-r2

We have 3 machines: One has Windows server OS 2012-r2 installed with decent specs (12 GB RAM, 3.6 GHz, 4 cores, 600 GB hard disk). The others are home laptops with regular specs of Ubuntu 20.04 & MacOS.  All are dealing with an SQLite DB.

In a loop, simple 4000 `SELECT - COUNT` queries are run to calculate certain value of a table row. This is followed by an `UPDATE` of that calculated value in another table. We notice that:

- In MacOS, it takes 2-3 mins
- In Ubuntu, it takes 5 mins
- In Windows, it takes 3 hours 8 mins!!!

Upon seeing logs, we noticed that every `SELECT + UPDATE` queries together take 1-3 seconds in Windows. *Moreover Ubuntu uses a core with 100% CPU for our program, while Windows server utilizes only < 2% only.*

This is a very significant difference. All are running the same source code. Is there anything we can do to make the *Windows server OS* performing the queries on par with Linux & MacOS?

Comment: Are they running the same version of SQLite? Have you checked that the database schemas involved are exactly the same? Do they have the same keys and indexes everywhere?

Comment: I **guess** that the bottleneck is *not* the `SELECT`, but the `UPDATE` that is run outside of a transaction. Again, I guess that if you run the whole process inside a single transaction, it will be *way* faster. On Windows in particular, it takes a huge time to synchronize the disk at the end of a transaction. On SQLite, if no transaction is on-going, a temporary transaction is created for each write. And that is slow.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, yes it should be the same version as we are compiling the "sqlite3.c" file with C++17 in Ubuntu/g++ & Windows/MSVC. The SQLite code is invoked via a same library code. I believe scehmas, keys & indexes *should* be same. How to check them in case? (I am not much hands-on with SQLite).

Comment: @prapin, how to run the whole process inside a single transaction? Can you answer this post with an example. It should be worth trying. Why this doesn't happen so in Ubuntu?

Comment: @iammilind I'm afraid I don't know how to check that in SQLite. :-(  I found [this list](https://dbmstools.com/categories/data-compare-tools/sqlite) of tools for SQLite that may be worth checking out.

Comment: @iammilind *how to run the whole process inside a single transaction?* I don't how your program is structured, nor how how you call SQLite from C++ (different bindings exist). But basically, you execute SQL query `BEGIN;` at startup, and `COMMIT;` when finished.

Comment: @prapin, yes I will try that. The `BEGIN / COMMIT` facility is available in the library we use. However, as per some [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/521887), it appears that the "transactions" are primarily used for maintaining data integrity. It will be interesting to see if that improves the disk performance as well, as you suggested. Is there any guidelines of how many SELECT / UPDATE queries to be performed under a single transaction?

Comment: @iammilind From experience, I can assure you that performance gain running everything inside a single transaction is HUGE on SQLite, in particular on Windows. On Linux, the gain is lower but still consequent. But that behavior doesn't necessarily transpose to other database systems. On PostgreSQL for example, I noticed nearly no performance difference. If you can afford to have a single transaction during the whole process, do it. But maybe you will need to `COMMIT` from time to time.

Comment: @prapin, thanks for your comment. It helped! The root cause is however within the code, which I posted as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the performance was worsening due to a **Mutex lock** every time before a `SELECT + UPDATE`. This was meant for the thread safety as the DB is expected to be accessed from the multiple threads.
After changing the design where the DB is now accessed from the single thread, the performance improved manifold. In Ubuntu it became 5X faster and in Windows it became 10X faster!!

[@prapin's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72514674/why-select-queries-run-slower-in-windows-server-machine-compared-to-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment128097897_72514674) also has some merit. We are now executing all the `UPDATE`s within a single transaction. This speeds up at least the Windows performance by 2X.

Comment: So the difference between Windows and Ubuntu may due to the difference of mutex between these two OSes?